# C++ class using Codeblocks

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ through C++ Primer book. It is about creating a class with some objects. Ireally do not know what to do to get the program to work. I am using CODEBLOCKS 13.12 and I have copy this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
    Sales_item book;
    //read ISBN, number of copies sold, and sales price
    std::cin>>book;
    //write ISBN, number of copies sold, total revenue, and average price
    std::cout<<book<<std:endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After that there is an error(I do not exactly what it is because only there is small red square on the right of this code line: `#include "Sales_item.h"`

I tried created a class(the author does not ask to do that) and two files were created:

```
Sales_item.h.h  

#ifndef SALES_ITEM_H_H
#define SALES_ITEM_H_H


class Sales_item.h
{
    public:
        Sales_item.h();
        virtual ~Sales_item.h();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // SALES_ITEM_H_H
```

and the second one:

```
Sales_item.h.cpp

#include "Sales_item.h.h"

Sales_item.h::Sales_item.h()
{
    //ctor
}

Sales_item.h::~Sales_item.h()
{
    //dtor
}
```

The author asks to copy the following code to the current directory. However I do not know what he means with "current directory".

```
/* This file defines the Sales_item class used in chapter 1.
* The code used in this file will be explained in
* Chapter 7 (Classes) and Chapter 14 (Overloaded Operators)
* Readers shouldn't try to understand the code in this file
* until they have read those chapters.
*/

#ifndef SALESITEM_H
// we're here only if SALESITEM_H has not yet been defined
#define SALESITEM_H

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
    // these declarations are explained section 7.2.1, p. 270
    // and in chapter 14, pages 557, 558, 561
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
    friend bool operator<(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
    friend bool operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item(): units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) { }
    Sales_item(const std::string &book):
    bookNo(book), units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);

    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;
// private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo; // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold;
    double revenue;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are those asterisks at the top a typo? If you are using a book, make sure you read it thoroughly, cut and pasting isn't the best way to learn generally.

Comment: This seems more like a CodeBlocks question than a C++ question.

Comment: Why are you naming your class "Sales_item.h"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author has "asked" you to copy the code into `Sales_item.h` file. Please delete your own class `Sales_item.h` comprising both files `Sales_item.h.h` and `Sales_item.h.cpp` and start over with author's `Sales_item.h` file and create `Sales_item.cpp` if needed.

The class name is `Sales_item`, not `Sales_item.h`.
Current directory means where your code resides.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I have created the Sales_item.h file and copied the code into that file. However in lines 10 (std::cin>>book;)and 12 (std::cout<<book<endl;) from the main.cpp file I see this error: undefined reference  to operator. I will appreciate very much any help you can give me.

Comment: @user3689783 Looks like you'll need to implement the `operator>>()` and `operator<<()` in the `Sales_item.h` or `Sales_item.cpp`.  The ones declared in the header file are just prototypes. You'll need to implement the function body.  Please read all the comments in the `class Sales_item` declaration in the `Sales_item.h` file.  As described in the comments, you might need to lookup the book to get further help.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually very cumbersome to write all your code in one file. So, C++ allows you to break your code in different files and then include it in the file you need it.

The `#include "Sales_item.h"` just tells the compiler to include all the code in the Sales_item.h in your current program.
The reason you get an error is that there is no Sales_item.h file in your computer!

You can get Sales_item.h and other resource files you might need for the book 
[here](http://www.informit.com/store/c-plus-plus-primer-9780321714114).
Copy Sales_item.h in the same directory as your code.

P.S. Try to write the examples on your own before you copy the resources.